# How to concatenate arrays using conditioning in Python?

Tags: python, concatenation

I have arrays 'a', 'b' and 'c'. I want to create the array 'd' using `concatenate()` and add a, b or c if they exist.

```
d = concatenate([a (if a exists),b (if b exists),c (if c exists)])
```

Comment: Are you using NumPy? are `a`,`b`,`c` NumPy arrays?

Comment: I actually extract them from pygadgetreader. For example: a = F[:, 0]

Comment: What do you mean by "if exists"? You're not sure if you actually created these arrays?

Comment: I want to make my code generic to situations where those arrays don't exist. I work with simulations of galaxies and sometimes there are no bulge particles, only dark matter and disk.

Comment: Exactly how do you extract a, b, and c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you want your ***d*** is a list of list.

```
a = []
b = ["B", "C"]
c = ["A", "C", "D"]

def concatenate(*args):
    return [item for item in args if item]

print(concatenate(a,b,c))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['B', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'D']]
```

But if you want just the values of a,b,c in to d:

```
a = []
b = ["B", "C"]
c = ["A", "C", "D"]

def concatenate(*args):
    return [item for arr in args for item in arr] 

print(concatenate(a,b,c))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'D']
```

The `*args` is for your function to accept multiple arguments/lists.

INPUT:

```
a = []
b = ["B", "C"]
c = ["A", "C", "D"]
d = ["X", "Z", "E"]
e = ["J", "H", "G"]
f = ["K", "L", "D"]

concatenate(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Z', 'E', 'J', 'H', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'D']
```

Comment: You can also just do ```a + b + c```

Comment: What does * mean here?

Comment: @DanielMarostica allows you to take in more arguments.

Comment: @Joshua Nixon, idk if OP wants a list of list or just the values of a,b,c in d

Comment: @Errol ```a + b + c``` doesn't produce a list of lists - it gives the same result as your list compensation but is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd have all the variables exist even if they are blank, so in your other code where you decide between creating the variable or not, instead, initialise it as [] before making your normal decision about whether to put a value in it or not, I believe this is standard practise for Python

This then means concatenate would just work

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays

```
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y
array([4, 5, 6])
```

concatenation can be done in multiple ways. E.g.

```
>>> [*x, *y]
>>> np.concatenate((x, y))
```

The output is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

As soon as you try to append 'z' which is not defined you will get a 'NameError'

```
>>> [*x, *y, *z]
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

So be sure to define every used variable first wether or not it will remain empty.

```
>>> z
array([])
>>> [*x, *y, *z]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

if your arrays a,b,c are of list type following code works,because an empty list is evaluated None by default in a truth test.Else modify lambda accordingly

```
d=list(filter(lambda x:x,[a+b+c]))
```

If any of the list a,b,c turns empty it will skip

Comment: Does d=[a,b,c] concatenates the three lists right away? No need of "concatenate()"?

Comment: My mistake i corrected it. I should have rechecked it. Try this.

Comment: '+' is the concatenation operator in python.